# can we play the content not from the start in hls playlist?

Tags: http-live-streaming

I have a hls playlist playlist.m3u8 file where the url's of all the chunks are there.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:10,
01-0.ts
#EXTINF:10,
01-1.ts
#EXTINF:10,
01-2.ts
#EXTINF:10,
01-3.ts
#EXTINF:10,
01-4.ts
#EXTINF:10,
01-5.ts
#EXTINF:10,
01-6.ts
#EXTINF:10,
01-7.ts
```

Even if I change the media sequence no to , say 5, it always plays from the start. Is there anyway that I can play the content from any given point i.e not always from the start ? Please help me.

Comment: Your playlist looks like a live playlist. It is very hard to control client behavior. One workaround is you can remove ts files, if you don't want them to get played. Just remember size of the playlist should be atleast 3 times the size of targetduration. So in your case you can remove all ts files older than 01-4.ts

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep all the segments in the playlist you can use the optional tag `#EXT-X-START:TIME-OFFSET=<seconds>`. This is available in version 6 of the protocol.

Source: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-12#section-3.4.16

Comment: @scaryguy It worked on an Apple device, if I remember correctly. The tag is optional and only works with version 6 of the protocol. Non-Apple players usually support 3-4.

Comment: @aergistal Does it apply for client side or server side? I want my Android app to start playing from a specified offset. Streaming server is my set-top box.

Comment: @anhtuannd The tag must be present in the master playlist, so it's on the  encoder side.

Comment: @aergistal Thank you! Is there any solution for player in Android client to start from specified offset?

Comment: @anhtuannd I think it depends on the playlist type. You can try a seek but I remember people saying it doesn't work on Live streams on Android. If you have VOD or Event it might work.